# Unrar4iOS error, File::tell() throws to asm code, what should I do?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rar, unrar

I have an error File::tell() shown in XCode, using Unrar4iOS Framework, when I am calling the method:

```
-(NSArray)unrarListFiles;
```

the compiler shows me the a bunch of errors, where the last from stack is ftell, if someone knows, the origin if where probabily i am wrong, plese reply...
the full procedure what i want to do is to extrat the int number of files archived, from code below:

```
int nuberOfPages = 0;
NSLog(@"Filepath: %@", filePath);
Unrar4iOS *_unrar = [[Unrar4iOS alloc] init];
BOOL ok = [_unrar unrarOpenFile:filePath];
if (ok) {

    NSArray *files = [_unrar unrarListFiles];
    for (NSString *filename in files) {
        NSLog(@"File: %@", filename);
    }
    nuberOfPages = files.count;

    [unrar unrarCloseFile];
} else {
    [unrar unrarCloseFile];
}
[_unrar release];
return nuberOfPages;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because that.
in source code.

```
-(BOOL) unrarOpenFile:(NSString*)rarFile



-(BOOL) unrarCloseFile
```

the function above. they did not do anything.

this function do real open and real close;

```
-(NSArray *) unrarListFiles {
int RHCode = 0, PFCode = 0;

    //here  if you opened a file that is not rar.
    //this function RARReadHeaderEx will EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    //so, you can check it return value
[self _unrarOpenFile:filename mode:RAR_OM_LIST];

NSMutableArray *files = [NSMutableArray array];
while ((RHCode = RARReadHeaderEx(_rarFile, header)) == 0) {
    NSString *_filename = [NSString stringWithCString:header->FileName encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [files addObject:_filename];

    if ((PFCode = RARProcessFile(_rarFile, RAR_SKIP, NULL, NULL)) != 0) {
        [self _unrarCloseFile];
        return nil;
    }
}

[self _unrarCloseFile];
return files;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in `Unrar4iOS` triggered by reading a corrupt RAR archive (or a file that is not a RAR archive at all). It attempts to read an address on disk that is not part of the archive, and throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`. I posted this as an issue in the GitHub project: https://github.com/ararog/Unrar4iOS/issues/6

Matt Gallagher wrote an article on [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html) showing how to try to present the error nicely to the user, but that code should *not* be used to keep your application running, as it may have unpredictable results.

**Update**: for what it's worth, I forked Unrar4iOS into a new project, [UnrarKit](https://github.com/abbeycode/UnrarKit), which handles errors using `NSError` instead of throwing exceptions.

Comment: i've found the issue, but i could not resolve it, i remaked UNRAR4IOS object so just it returns me throw, and in try statement i get the error !!

Comment: There is no way in Cocoa to catch unix signals, like `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: you should rewrite unrar4iOS method extract stream:

Comment: while ((RHCode = RARReadHeaderEx(_rarFile, header)) == 0) {
  NSString *_filename = [NSString stringWithCString:header->FileName encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        
  if ([_filename isEqualToString:aFile]) {
   length = header->UnpSize;
   break;
  } 
  else {
   if ((PFCode = RARProcessFile(_rarFile, RAR_SKIP, NULL, NULL)) != 0) {
    [self _unrarCloseFile];
                
    return nil;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: in the .mm file, extract stream method, there is no error chech

Comment: i added thew else to find if the erro persists, it should throw me back, with an exception !!!

Comment: It seems like you've performed some useful troubleshooting steps, but it's difficult to read your code in comments. Can you update your question to include the code you modified in `Unrar4iOS`?

Comment: - (BOOL)rarOpenFile:(NSString *)rarFile mode:(NSInteger)mode

Comment: and exactly after RAROpenArchiveEx(flags); 
you get the result in flags->OpenResult, it must return a 0 if its ok, otherwise its an error, shown below:

ERAR_END_ARCHIVE    = 10;
  ERAR_NO_MEMORY      = 11;
  ERAR_BAD_DATA       = 12;
  ERAR_BAD_ARCHIVE    = 13;
  ERAR_UNKNOWN_FORMAT = 14;
  ERAR_EOPEN          = 15;
  ERAR_ECREATE        = 16;
  ERAR_ECLOSE         = 17;
  ERAR_EREAD          = 18;
  ERAR_EWRITE         = 19;
  ERAR_SMALL_BUF      = 20;
  ERAR_UNKNOWN        = 21;